# Akka Actor system TestActorRef - trying to understand the meaning of TestActorRef[T <: Actor]

Tags: java, scala

Okay, I am trying to get my head wrapped around Akka actors. 
I looked at the following source code from TestActorRef.scala and want to get a hold of the details:

```
class TestActorRef[T <: Actor](
  _system: ActorSystem,
  _props: Props,
  _supervisor: ActorRef,
  name: String)
```

Okay, here is one thing I readily noticed and understand about the constructor concept in Scala. It is that TestActorRef comes with a 4-parameter constructor and those parameters are: **_system: ActorSystem, _props: Props, 
_supervisor: ActorRef, name: String**
(this is apparent from the API also)

What I do not get is the '[T <: Actor]" part.

 My broad hunch is,  it is along the same lines as a Generic Java class bearing the signature, but with the caveat that Scala being a deeper language, there is more to it than meets the eye. 

 
So, in Java, we have a generic class definition as follows:

```
class name<t1, T2, ...Tn) { /**   */}
```

Where T1, T2, T3 are type parameters or type variables.
I went back to the API to find the equivalent version of this class in Java, which is:
and I find that the declaration is:

```
public class TestActorRef<T extends Actor>
```

so, we have: 
    `<T extends Actor>` - in Java

 and 
    `[T <: Actor]` - in Scala. 
 
What is the meaning of the Scala version? What is that "<:" operator or "keyword". 
How different is it from the Java version?

All these would help me accomplish my goal of having a better handle of TestActorRef and testing Akka Actors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'T <: Actor' means any type T if T is subtype of Actor. This has the same meaning as `<T extends Actor>` in Java. In Scala `T <: ...` is called **upper type bound**. You can find the precise definition [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/136)

Comment: That answers my question nicely. Thanks